# Cannot find my Windows bootloader screen

Tags: windows

I had installed `ubuntu` on my laptop some days back. Feeling no longer use for it I simply `deleted` the two drives on which ubuntu was installed via windows 7 and merged them to a certain partition. Now, I cannot see my `old windows bootloader screen`. I tried finding it out over the web and they said to run the wiondows repair from the installation disk but my disk has no such option available throughout the installtion process.

Is there any other way possible to `restore my bootloader screen`?

Answer (score 0):

- Boot windows installation disk the there was a `windows repair` option before you go into the installation,select it.
- After selecting windows repair option,it will take you to the next screen.In that screen select the `command prompt` option
- Then run the below commands,on it.

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /rebuildbcd
  ```
- Atlast restart your pc.