# Grub rescue error⠀

Tags: grubrescue

I recently dual booted my computer to have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 on it. I later decided that I didn't want Ubuntu, so in Windows 7 I went to Disk Management and deleted 2 volumes that were not there before I made an Ubuntu partition, and then when I restarted my computer all that came up on the screen was:

```
error: no such partition 
grub rescue>
```

What does this mean? What do I do to either boot into Windows or Linux? Any help is appreciated. I am very new to Linux. Thank you!

Comment: Just re-install your Windows bootloader.[This](http://askubuntu.com/a/381505/202806) answer will help you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error is: You need to re-define the partitions and the operating systems in them, to your bootloader, because you've removed some of the partitions. This is defined in something that we call **Master Boot Record**. In this case, you could go on with using GRUB since you have it installed, especially if you want to go on installing other operating systems in the future.

The other option is that you could switch to the Windows bootloader and rewrite the MBR because you won't be using anything other than Windows for the rest of your life.

- If you want to fix the broken GRUB, you need the prepare a [GRUB Boot Repair USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Then all you need to do is to boot the USB and click "Recommended Repair" which is really easy.
- If you want to switch to Windows Bootloader, then you need the Windows Installation Disc that you need to buy from Amazon as a DVD or illegally download or something. When you boot from it, use the steps here Avinash Raj has already posted: [Fix Windows Bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381503/cannot-find-my-windows-bootloader-screen/381505#381505)